# Debugging CalculateField_management ERROR 000623: Invalid value type for parameter field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, error-000628, error-000622

I am trying to select records in my table that have certain words in the "Name" field and then code them as 0 (not pharmacy) or 1 (pharmacy)  This is just a test searching for two words to select non-pharmacies.

I am getting a:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Calculate Field).
>   Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000623: Invalid value type for
>   parameter field.

I don't know which variable is invalid.  Any thoughts?  I also do not know if the Calculate Field will work on only the records selected.  I cannot get far enough to check that.

```
# import system modules
import arcpy
import random

# set workspace environment
myWorkspace = arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/PharmacyProtocol/tables"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# set variables
out_table = "VT_TRL_DLC.dbf"

# set field variables
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(out_table)

for field in fieldList:
    if field.name == "Name":
        nameF = field
    elif field.name == "Pharmacy":
        pharmF = field

#create list of words that are NOT pharmacies
noPharmWords = ['AMERICAN LEGION','BAR']

expression = 0

#find words in Name field, code Pharmacy as "0" if not already coded
for codeWord in noPharmWords:

#create SQL text clause
fldName = '"Name"'
endClause = "%'"
SQLstr = fldName + " LIKE '%" + codeWord + endClause

#select records from table with codeWord
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_table, ["Name"], SQLstr)

arcpy.CalculateField_management(out_table, pharmF, expression)

del cursor
```

Comment: Looks like you have some minor formatting issues, need a indentation after > for codeWord in noPharmWords:  Also you have some dead code in this loop > for field in fieldList:

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be misusing the cursor. `arcpy.CalculateField_management()` will operate on the entire table or table view it is given, regardless of any cursor object's existence. It's probably failing because you're passing a field *object* rather than a field *name* to it.

Try using an update cursor instead, replacing this:

```
#select records from table with codeWord
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_table, ["Name"], SQLstr)

arcpy.CalculateField_management(out_table, pharmF, expression)

del cursor
```

with this:

```
#select records from table with codeWord
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(out_table, ["Name","Pharmacy"], SQLstr) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = expression
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the field an integer type, you might try expression = int(0). Calculate field will work on selected records only or all records if none are selected. Will Calculate field 0 work from the attribute table for that field?

Only other option I can suggest is to comment out the CalcField function and maybe do something else that proves the cursor is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

To determine why you are receiving that error I would recommend replacing:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(out_table, pharmF, expression)
```

with:

```
print out_table
print pharmF
print expression
arcpy.CalculateField_management(out_table, pharmF, expression)
```

I suspect that you are not supplying CalculateField_management with the parameter values that you think you are.